# Java open live file at runtime

Tags: java, csv, runtime, filewriter

I have a table of data and i wanted an export function, this application run on web so i want to create a csv file and then offer (open or save as option) usual download options. Im using CSV writer at the moment.
The line in question here is `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("export.csv");` give error listed at bottom
How would i do this?

Here is the action tied to a button

```
Action exportData = new Action() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7803023178172634837L;

    @Override   
    public void execute(UIContext uic, ActionEvent event) {

        try{       
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("export.csv"), '\t');
            int i = 0;
            while (i < forExport.getTotalCount()){
                String[] entries = {
                    forExport.getSearchResults().get(i).getName().getGivenNames() + forExport.getSearchResults().get(i).getName().getSurname(),
                    forExport.getSearchResults().get(i).getId()
                };
                writer.writeNext(entries);
                i++;
            }  
            writer.close();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("export.csv");  
        }catch(Exception e){
            system.out.print(e);
        }
    }
};
```

getting error `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export.csv": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 applicationDEBUG`

NOTE: i do not want it to automatically open in excel, i want the option to save or open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are exec-ing anything whatsoever. This is server code. You don't want to exec Excel at the server at all. You want to write the file back to the browser, along with a content-disposition header.

Comment: indeed, exac was there as a way i had done similar things in the past not on server, i didn't think it was right. thanks. Do you know of any good examples of writeing the file back to the browser, along with a content-disposition header.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("excel.exe export.csv");
```

`export.csv` is not a valid windows command.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "excel.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specifiedDEBUG

Comment: Try with fixed path from program files from `Dos` prompt. It will be not in the path then. I am on Ubuntu otherwise I could have tried on my own. If it works on `Dos prompt` then it works with `exec`

Comment: i don't want it automatically being opened in excel, i just want to download the csv file, i cannot use fixed paths as it is a web app and independant of a particular machine.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec() will never help you to download a file. If you are writing web application then it is done differently. You can refer tutorial over [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/) for the same.

Comment: maybe not worded so well in the question. i didnt want to use exac only, i just hadnt done this and that is how i did non server side things in the past

Comment: You can use this [How to download file from website- Java / Jsp](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/) to get to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A .csv file is  a comma separated value file which is used to keep data. and the parameter of the exec command is the command as string to open the .csv file. But in your command string you have not specified any program with which the runtime should try to open the .csv file.

As a .csv file is not executable, In the command string parameter specify the program name with ahich you want to open the ..csv file.